# Plotting over multiple dictionary values using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot values stored in lists as dict values but I have gotten stuck. Heres an example of the structure of the dictionary and my code to iterate over die keys and values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mydict = {
"A":
[1.0, 0.75, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5],
"B":
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0],
"C":
[0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.75, 0.25, 0.0, -1, 0.5, 0.75, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
"D":
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2]}

for k, v in mydict.iteritems():   
    plt.title('Some data for unit: ' + k)
    plt.xlabel('Number of data points')
    plt.ylabel('Some unit')
    plt.figure(k)
    xs = range(0, len(v))
    ys = v
    plt.plot(xs, ys, '-.')
    plt.show
```

Im a relative beginner and I probably missed something basic and essential, but the following always happens: The first plot comes out empty with the title for unit A and the last one has no title or labels. So Im guessing it mocks up an empty plot for Unit A, plots data for Unit A in the second plot, Unit B in plot three and so forth until the fifth plot, which I did not expect to be there, considering my dict only has four key value pairs.

What am I missing here? Ive tried for hours and just cant come up with a solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create the figure `plt.figure()` *before*  giving it a title. Then you need to decide if you want to show all figures at once (`plt.show()` outside the loop), or one-by-one (inside the loop). *But*, make sure to actually *call* `plt.show()` - mind the `()`.

```
for k, v in mydict.iteritems():  
    plt.figure(k) 
    plt.title('Some data for unit: ' + k)
    plt.xlabel('Number of data points')
    plt.ylabel('Some unit')
    xs = range(0, len(v))
    ys = v
    plt.plot(xs, ys, '-.')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new plot by giving a title. After that that you call `plt.figure(k)`, creating another new plot. This is the plot where the data of the current loop will be plotted in. In the next loop you give *this* plot a new title. That's why everything seems shifted.

Move `plt.figure(k)` to the top of the loop. You can also just call `plt.figure()` if you don't care about the number of the figure, which -- in most cases -- you don't.

Also `plt.show` just refers to the function, but you need to call it: `plt.show()`

Comment: Thank you! As I said, Im missing some essentials. Ill be sure not to make that mistake again.